# Is Jboss EAP 7.2 backward compatible with Servlet 3.0

Tags: jboss7.x

I have to upgrade from Jboss EAP 6.4 to Jboss EAP 7.2. About Servlet, I see here https://access.redhat.com/articles/113373 that 7.2 supports Servlet 4.0. Does it mean it does not support Servlet 3.0 anymore?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it supports Servlet 3.0.

In general there is backward compatibility with prior servlet specs, and containers are required to support deployment descriptors for all versions. In fact, Servlet 4.0 only has a section about backward compatibility with Servlet 2.5 regarding the meaning of the `metadata-complete` element.